# Create automatically Google docs with App Script( need example )

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need examples or informations about Google Doc with App Script.
I need to create automatically a Google doc with my App Script.

Where can I find more examples for my work to build a Google doc?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs) guide

Actually to create a doc you will only need to do this:

```
function createDoc() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rowsData = [['Plants', 'Animals'], ['Ficus', 'Goat'], ['Basil', 'Cat'], ['Moss', 'Frog']];
  body.insertParagraph(0, doc.getName())
  .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but I need example for example use design on this document.  it's possible ?

Comment: Edited the answer, please check if is it ok.